# Ant is looking in wrong directory despite having the correct environment variable set

Tags: java, ant

I have my JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40; which is where it is located. When I run Ant I get this error.

```
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

The jre7 file and the jdk1.7.0_40 files are located right next to each other. Any idea what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to execute `ant` command from directory where build.xml exists not from bin directory of ant.

Comment: @PradeepSimha is right.  If I recall correctly, missing tools.jar is just a warning.  Running from the `bin` directory is certainly the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run ant in the same directory as the `build.xml` file.   Alternately, `ant -f path/to/build.xml`